# Не работает синус, ассемблер, код на си

Tags: c, ассемблер

Написала программу, не вычисляется синус. Нигде не смогла найти нормальное описание правил синтаксиса

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <locale>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    float r, u, x, y;
    float a = -1;
    printf("Print X, Y:\n");
    if (!(scanf("%f %f", &x, &y))) //ввод Х и У + проверка на правильный ввод данных: если не читаются числа, выдает ошибку
    {
        printf("Error.Try again"); //вывод ошибки
    } else {
        //определяем и инициализируем указатели
        float *X = &x; // в asm(1) будет %1
        float *Y = &y; // в asm(1) будет %2
        float *R = &r; // в asm(1) будет %0
        float *U = &u; // в asm(2) будет %0
        float *A = &a; // в asm(2) будет %0

        asm // решаем алгоритм r=sqrt(x*x+y*y);
        (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix \n\t" //синтаксис Intel, допускается опускание % перед именами регистров
        "movss xmm1, [%2] \n\t" //Заносим данные в регистр (х)
        "movss xmm2, [%2] \n\t" //Заносим данные в регистр (х)
        "mulss xmm1, xmm2 \n\t" //Умножаем х*х
        "movss xmm3, [%3] \n\t" //Заносим данные в регистр (y)
        "movss xmm2, [%3] \n\t" //Заносим данные в регистр (y)
        "mulss xmm2, xmm3 \n\t" //Умножаем y*y
        "addss xmm1, xmm2 \n\t" //Суммируем х*х и y*y
        "sqrtss xmm1, xmm1 \n\t" // ax,ax //Квадратный корень из (х*х+y*y)
        "movss [%0], xmm1 \n\t" //Вывод данных из регистра
        :"=r"(R) //возвращаемые данные(выходные операнды),нумеруются с нуля
        :"r"(R), "r"(X), "r"(Y) //Входные данные(продолжение нумерации)
        :"%xmm1", "%xmm2", "%xmm3" //Разрушение регистров
        );

        //r=sqrt(x*x+y*y);
        if (r == 0) //условие, если r=0 - радиус, одна из компонентов полярной системы координат
        {
            U = 0;
            printf("R=%f\n", r);
            printf("U=%f\n", u);
        };
        //U=asin(y/r);
        asm // решаем алгоритм asin(y/r);;
        (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix \n\t" //синтаксис Intel, допускается опускание % перед именами регистров
        "movss xmm1, [%3] \n\t" //Заносим данные в регистр (y)
        "movss xmm2, [%2] \n\t" //Заносим данные в регистр (R) = r из условия выше
        "divss xmm1, xmm2 \n\t" // Делим у на r
        "fsin \n\t" // cx, ax //Sin (y/r)
        "movss [%0],xmm1 \n\t" //cx //Вывод данных из регистра
        :"=r"(U) //возвращаемые данные(выходные операнды),нумеруются с нуля
        :"r"(U), "r"(R), "r"(Y) //Входные данные(продолжение нумерации)
        :"%xmm1", "%xmm2", "%xmm3" //Разрушение регистров
        );
        if ((x < 0) && (y >= 0)) {
            asm // решаем алгоритм U=M_PI-U (доп. условия с учетом четвертей тригонометрии)
            (
            ".intel_syntax noprefix \n\t" //синтаксис Intel, допускается опускание % перед именами регистров
            "movss xmm1, [%2] \n\t" //Заносим данные в регистр (M_PI) - число pi
            "movss xmm2, [%1] \n\t" //Заносим данные в регистр (u)
            "subss xmm1, xmm2 \n\t" //Вычитаем U из M_PI
            "movss [%0], xmm1 \n\t" //Вывод данных из регистра
            :"=r"(U) //возвращаемые данные(выходные операнды),нумеруются с нуля
            :"r"(U), "r"(M_PI) //Входные данные(продолжение нумерации)
            :"%xmm1", "%xmm2" //Разрушение регистров
            );
        } else if ((x < 0) && (y < 0)) {
            asm // решаем алгоритм U=(-1)*M_PI-U (доп. условия с учетом четвертей тригонометрии)
            (
            ".intel_syntax noprefix \n\t" //синтаксис Intel, допускается опускание % перед именами регистров
            "movss xmm1, [%2] \n\t" //Заносим данные в регистр (M_PI) - число pi
            "movss xmm2, [%3] \n\t" //Заносим данные в регистр (a=-1)
            "mulss xmm1, xmm2 \n\t" //Умножаем a на M_PI
            "movss xmm2, [%1] \n\t" //Заносим данные в регистр (u)
            "subss xmm1, xmm2 \n\t" //Вычитаем из -M_PI U
            "movss [%0], xmm1 \n\t" //Вывод данных из регистра
            :"=r"(U) //возвращаемые данные(выходные операнды),нумеруются с нуля
            :"r"(U), "r"(M_PI), "r"(A) //Входные данные(продолжение нумерации)
            :"%xmm1", "%xmm2" //Разрушение регистров
            );
        };
        printf("R=%f\n", r); //вывод значений
        printf("U=%f\n", u); //вывод значений
    }
}
```

Comment: В наборе инструкций SSE нет тригонометрических функций.

Comment: Вы пользуетесь одновременно SSE (команды `MOVSS`, `SUBSS`, регистры `XMM*`) и командой для сопроцессора (FPU) `FSIN`, работающей с другим набором регистров. Как говорят [тут](https://rsdn.org/forum/cpp.applied/4487610.all), отдельной команды вычисления синуса в SSE нет, так что Вам надо либо расписывать его вычисление множеством SSE команд, либо же сделать копирование в регистры FPU и вычислять там (что выглядит не очень), либо же пользоваться только FPU

Comment: к делу не относится, но по логике и по коментариям там должен быть _**арк**синус_

Answer (score 0):

Перед командой `fsin`, нужно перебросить значение из регистра `xmm2` в стек `FPU`.

Answer (score 0):

> Нигде не смогла найти нормальное описание правил синтаксиса

Непонятно, зачем здесь использовать инструкции SSE, если они не предназначены для тригонометрии? Загружайте свои значения сразу в сопр.FPU и производите  вычисления в нём. Вот пример на ассемблере fasm:

```
;// Решаем алгоритм: R = sqrt(x*x+y*y)
   fld      [Y]
   fmul     st0,st0  ;// y*y
   fld      [X]
   fmul     st0,st0  ;// x*x
   fadd     st0,st1  ;// x+y
   fsqrt             ;// sqrt(x*x+y*y)
   fstp     [R]      ;// R = результат

;// Решаем алгоритм: U = sin(Y/R)
   fld      [Y]
   fdiv     [R]      ;// y/R
   fsin              ;// sin(Y/R)
   fstp     [U]      ;// U = результат
   finit             ;// Очистить стек FPU
```

Comment: выдает ошибку и говорит, что перед ";"  должно быть что-то еще. Что там может/должно быть?